# android: radio buttons inside radio buttons

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

I am quite new to Android and this is my first application, so please correct if my question is not clear and I will gladly add more information about what I am trying to achieve.
I have a radio group built dynamically. Inside this radio group I would like to have another radio group, depending on the radio button chosen from the first group.
So, let's say I have an array list of items and for each item I have some sizes available (i.e: XS, S, L). If I check the radio button "XS", I would like to have another radio group with the available colors for the selected size, XS. 
The way I have built this is by creating a radio group and it's radio buttons dynamically. Inside the method onCheckedChanged(), I am calling the method createRadioButtonsForAvailableColors(). This one creates the radio buttons with the necessary colors for the checked size, but once I check another size in the upper radio group, the new colors available for this size are added to the colors shown for the size selected before. 
Thank you. 
Here is my on create method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_product_details);

    sizesList = getSizes(getIDFromPreviousActivity());
    createRadioButtonsForAvailableSizes(sizesList);     
}
```

Here is my creation for the radio group containing the radio buttons with the available sizes:

```
// creates the radio buttons with the available sizes   
public void createRadioButtonsForAvailableSizes(ArrayList<String>  sizeList) {
    productDetailsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.productDetailsLayout);
    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);


    int n = sizeList.size();
    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[n];
    for(int i=0; i< sizeList.size(); i++) {
        colorList = getColors(getIDFromPreviousActivity(),sizeList.get(i));

         rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
         rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
         rg.addView(rb[i]);
         rb[i].setText(sizesList.get(i).toString());
         rb[i].setId(getIDForRadioButton(sizesList.get(i).toString()));
         rb[i].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.radiobuttonunchecked);
         rb[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    }
    productDetailsLayout.addView(rg);
    productDetailsLayout.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
}
```

Here is the creation of the colors (same as for the sizes):

```
// create radio buttons for available colors
public void createRadioButtonsForAvailableColors(ArrayList<String>  colorList) {

    Log.d("createRadioButtonsForAvailableColors","");
    productDetailsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.productDetailsLayout);
    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);


    int n = colorList.size();
    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[n];
    for(int i=0; i< colorList.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("color"+i,colorList.get(i));
         rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
         rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
         rg.addView(rb[i]);
         rb[i].setText(colorList.get(i).toString());
         rb[i].setId(getIDForRadioButton(colorList.get(i).toString()));
         rb[i].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.radiobuttonunchecked);

         rb[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
                    button.setButtonDrawable(isChecked ? R.drawable.radiobuttonchecked : R.drawable.radiobuttonunchecked);
                }
         });

    }
    productDetailsLayout.addView(rg);
    productDetailsLayout.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
}
```

Here is my onCheckedChange method:

```
     @Override 
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
        button.setButtonDrawable(isChecked ? R.drawable.radiobuttonchecked : R.drawable.radiobuttonunchecked);
        String text = button.getText().toString();
        int productID = getIDFromPreviousActivity();
        ArrayList<String> colorList = getColors(productID, text);
        createRadioButtonsForAvailableColors(colorList);
    }
```

The inner group is created right, but upon checking one size in the first group, it builds the subgroup radio buttons normally. If I click one size, it shows the available colors. But, on changing the size checked, the buttons showing the colors of the now selected size are added to the buttons shown before for the previous size selected. How can I cancel the inner buttons created when I selected first time the size and show only the available colors for the currently selected size?

I think this is maybe not the right approach to build it. So, I have 2 questions:

1. Usually, what would be the best way to do this? Since my inner radio group depends on the radio button chosen from the first group, I assume the creation of the inner group should be called inside the onCheckedChange() method. Should I start another activity from here or can I do it all in one activity?
2. If my approach is correct, can you please tell me how to delete the inner radio buttons created, in case the radio button from the main group is changed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understood this, the problem comes when you change the value of the sizes radio button, meaning the colors don't disappear.

1. Well, Java is all about a lot of boilerplating, and there's not pretty much to say (I'd probably go for a similar way).
2. You could add this inside the `createRadioButtonsForAvailableColors` method, just before you start adding content:

`productDetailsLayout.removeViews(0, productDetailsLayout.getChildCount());`

[RemoveViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeViews%28int,%20int%29) will remove any amount of child views starting from a position (hence I amb passing it 0 and the total of children).

Comment: Thank you for the answer: Yes, if I select let's say "XS" for example, it shows the available colors for the XS size. If then I select "S" size, it adds the S available colors underneath the XS available colors. I know from the code that the available color list is build right according to the size, this is only a display issue. Yes, this might help removing the first children created. Let me see if it works. Would it be better to call another activity if I would have to do this right?

Comment: If by calling another activity to do this you mean loading the child radio buttons in another activity, well, that depends on what makes more sense to your application. I'd personally go for a `DialogFragment`, as you can generate even one with just a list of radio buttons without the hassle of create/remove views. So when you click on a size, a dialogfragment pops up with a list of available colors. When you select one, the dialog is dismissed and the selected value returned to you by one of the DialogFragment events.

Comment: Check a little more info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html But hey, again, this radically changes your question, so don't make changes blindly, and dedicate a little time to choose what's the best for your interface.

Comment: I have tried it there, it removes also the sizes list above also. So it has to be moved somewhere else so that it removes only the colors

Comment: Exactly, I forgot to mention that. However, you can actually change the `0` for the amount of sizes you have. So if you have, say, 4 sizes, change it to `productDetailsLayout.removeViews(4, productDetailsLayout.getChildCount()-4);`

Comment: Hi Korcholis, yes, I meant loading the child buttons in another activity, sorry if I do not have yet the right expressions. I'll try removing the views as it suits better my UI needs, but I will check also the DialogFragment, I have never used it before

Comment: This could help, but the sizes are available according to the available number of items, so it changes dynamically. Maybe I can subtract the colorList.size found

Comment: Exactly. 4 was just an example, but you can store the amount in a variable and use that instead. Especially if you're using it multiple times. Give DialogFragment a try. It lets you clean a lot the interface (if what you want still makes sense when used in a dialog, of course). Also, if you're going to use this colors approach all across your app, you could also pay attention to Fragments in general, as they let you reuse code in your whole app, letting you define different layout implementations based on screen size, orientation... even language or country.

Comment: In my .xml layout I have a single LinearLayout. Would it be better to have two? One for the sizes and another one for the colors? no matter what I do I keep deleting the sizes also when I delete the colors

Comment: As long as it still makes sense to the interface, then it's ok. Have you tried, however, to use a Spinner (which is actually a regular dropdown)? That way you wouldn't have this issues, would still make sense, you could populate it using an adapter.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have read now. I think a drop down list would look nice and suit better my needs actually. I'll see this with a drop down list and, according to the size selected, check the available colors in another drop down list

Comment: I have solved it with 2 spinners today, thanks for the tip. I'll be coming back more with other questions as I go on with my application. Thanks again

Comment: great, but add them as new questions, checking before if they already exist